# Viewing style modifications in Firefox Devtools' page inspector

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools, inspector

Firefox devtools inspector provides a very convenient interface for modifying CSS rules of any element, so that one may toy around and see the results of it live in the rendered webpage window of Firefox. You can enable and disable rules, and so on.

Now what happens when I've got it just the way I like it to look? How can I see everything I did? My changes are scattered all throughout the DOM with rule modifications throughout. How can I see only what was changed so I can understand the changes and migrate them back to my stylesheets on disk?